# Selenium isn't logging in to WP-Admin on some sites, and stuck in reauth loop

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Having weird issues with no indication of what it could be.
This is my login function:

```
    def login(self):
        # Open Firefox Window
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.maximize_window()
        print("I'm getting the URL")

        # Get User wp-admin Input
        driver.get(self.wp.text() + '/wp-admin/post-new.php')

        print("I Got the URL")

        # Find Input Fields
        username_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#user_login')
        password_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#user_pass')

        print("I found the fields")

        # Send Username and Password and submit
        username_field.send_keys(self.username.text())
        password_field.send_keys(self.password.text())
        password_field.submit()
        print("I pressed submit")
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(EC.url_contains('wp-admin/post-new.php'))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
        print(driver)

        if self.r1.isChecked():
            print("single selected")
            # Single Post
            self.single(driver)

        elif self.r2.isChecked():
            print("multiple selected")
            # Multiple Post Creation
            self.multiple(driver)
```

So I used a very slow website to test this on, and everything seems to work just fine, I've tested that particular site over and over again with no issues.
Then when I tried running the same bot on other websites, it's acting weird with no errors which gives me no indication of what might be the problem.

Sometimes when I submit the form, it just stays on the same page over and over and over again, even when I manually push the submit button, it clears the password field and stays on the page (wp-login).

Other times, and the more weird part, is that it will log in, but will not forward to the '/wp-admin/post-new.php' page, instead it goes to the /wp-admin/, and when manually clicking the new post button in the WP panel, it will log me back out of the website and ask me to log back in...

I've been using this login function in many other applications I've built and there has never been an issue.

I have filled the entire script with prints to see where the issue might occur, and it runs well, it's finishing the entire block and even goes to the self.multiple or self.single block and executes it, only to fail in a driver.find_element line because of the issue stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `password_field.submit()` have you tried finding the actual login button and clicking it?

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#login_button')
login_button.click()
```

Another possible solution that comes to mind is using a dedicated login-page for WP for the authentication and after successful authentication, retrieving the content page you want in a new `driver.get()` request. That should help with possible redirects and the reauth loop.

Comment: I have, clicking the actual button has the same result.

I have tried to first login and then get the new post page, and it just logs me out and back to the auth page

Comment: Hmm in that case I'd update possible upgradeable component requirements: firefox, geckodriver, selenium itself. Other than that I can't think of anything other than maybe a configurational issue somewhere - are you preserving cookies and local storage? If you haven't tried, run the script in non-headless mode to see if you can spot an error.

Comment: Another idea that occurred: are you sure the page gets fully loaded after login, and the url isn't portraying the wanted string before having time to process the login fully? You could try this out by just adding a crude wait of 10 seconds or so after login. There might be an url with e.g. "redirect=wp-admin/post-new.php" etc. before the actual login has proceeded. If that works, you can verify the page load by for example trying to find a certain element from the page in a loop.